# Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' on heroku push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

When i do git push heroku master ,it fails at rake assets precompile and i get an error `Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' heroku`

**What i already know**
Since i am using Rails 4,Definitely `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` is out of the picture because is no longer required.

`heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` this feature is no longer supported by Heroku.

After doing research online, I learned that the solution might be here 
[heroku build pack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api)
But i don't understand how to run those commands.
I keep getting `bash: bin/compile: No such file or directory`

How do i resolve this issue? I am using Rails 4.2.5 ,Ruby 2.3.0 and the Db is Mysql locally.Thank you in advance.

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: password
host: localhost

development:
<<: *default
database: respect_development

test:
<<: *default
database: respect_test

production:

   <<: *default
database: respect_production
username: respect
password: <%= ENV['RESPECT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `database.yml` is configured to use a local database (`127.0.0.1`) even on Heroku. What is in your `database.yml`? I would remove that file from git and check your Heroku config vars for `DATABASE_URL`. You should see a reference to the database on Heroku, *not* `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: heroku config says  "my-app  has no config vars". I am not very good with heroku. How do i set these?

Comment: I just added `/config/database.yml` in my .gitignore  and i did `git rm config/database.yml` , after commit and push still i get the same error(still connected to 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Just type `heroku config`. If you have multiple apps for this project you mean need to add `--app=asfdasfdfads`. There will be quite a few lines with important credentials, so don't copy/paste them here. But you should see one with `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Also: I'm pretty sure you must `git rm` and `git commit` *before* adding the file to `.gitignore` because otherwise your changes will be ignored (natually). At least I seem to recall having that problem a few years ago.

Comment: Yes i did that it says , `my-app has no config vars`

Comment: Also to answer "How do I set these?" You don't want to set them (at least for this problem). If you app has a database, Heroku should add a config var with its URL.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to precompile assets `rake assets:precompile` locally and then push it `git push  heroku master`
and in my **environments/production.rb**

`config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`

Also i added this to my Gemfile

```
group :production do
   gem 'rails_12factor'
  end
```